# Move a file between a site libraries

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I created the App integrated with Microsoft Graph that allows users to manage files in their SharePoint sites.

I'm having trouble with [moving a files](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/driveitem_move) between different Site Libraries (lists, drives ).

Site a request looks like:

```
PATCH
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{id}/drives/{id}/root:/myfile.docx
```

And new destination is set like:

```
/sites/{id}/drives/{id}/root:/myfolder
```

This request works good if source Drive is the same as the destination Drive. But if they are different (different top level folders of a site) I get this error:

> One of the provided arguments is not acceptable.

Is there any workaround?
Maybe it is not allowed to move a file between different drives?

UPDATE.

Also, i found that moving a file to a top of a folder doesn't work. If a site has a folder A (list or library ) it is not possible to move a file from some subfolder to it . From A/B to A.

I can move from A to A/B . BUt can not move from A/B to A .

Request looks like

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/SITEID/drives/LISTDRIVEID/root:/_trash/B/15.docx

{"parentReference":{"path":"\/sites\/SITEID\/drives\/LISTDRIVEID\/root"}}
```

LISTDRIVEID is ID of a top level folder as a drive (returned in SITEID/drives/ request)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues with your request:

1. You cannot use `root:` in your destination, you need to use the actual `id` value.
2. You need to issue a `PATCH` with an `application/json` body that looks like this:

```json
{
    "parentReference": {
        "id": "{destination-id}"
    },
    "name": "myfile.docx"
}
```

Comment: Yes. I use the PATCH body. root: works fine if i move a file to the root of a list (library) where it is located. but if other library than doesn't work . no to root of other library, no to any subfolder.

Comment: You cannot use the path, you need to specify the actual `id` from the root folder. Paths (i.e. `root:`) is not supported when moving between drives.

Comment: I tried to use ID. There are 2 IDs for each library. On is ID returned for it when do the request SITEID/lists and other is ID returned by SITEID/drives . I tried for both and got "Not found" for both

Comment: This isn't the drive id, rather the root folder id. Try the I'd you get from `SITEID/drives/DRIVEID/root` .